# How to populate a WinForms ComboBox with SharePoint list choice values?

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint

`Products` are a list with one choice field, `Country`. There are 3 possible choices. How can I load them into a Windows Forms combo box? This is the code I have:

```
private void populateDropbox()
{
  SPClient.List myList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Products");
  SPFieldChoice field = (SPFieldChoice)myList.Fields["Country"];

  foreach (string choice in field.Choices)
  {
    comboBox1.Items.Add(choice);
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error that ["Country"] cannot be converted to int.
I don't need it converted to int. How can I fix this code?

Comment: Are you sure that fields contains "Country"? (and not something like "country"). I would debug and check the fields to ensure that it contains that entry and see what the value of that entry is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us more of your code. Which API are you using? Which version of SharePoint?

As a quick guess... try changing:

```
myList.Fields["Country"]
```

to:

```
myList.Fields.GetByTitle("Country")
```

Answer (score 0):

Client side object model(seems you used CSOM and SSOM together)?

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp"))
            {
                var web = context.Web;
                var myList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test");
                var field = myList.Fields.GetByTitle("Options");
                context.Load(field);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                FieldChoice choiceField = context.CastTo<FieldChoice>(field);
                foreach (string choice in choiceField.Choices)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(choice);
                }

            }
```

[image]